# SQL - is there a way to order results by how many `OR`'s it maches? (laravel)

Tags: sql, where-clause

I have this query:

```
SELECT * FROM articles
    WHERE name LIKE '%test%'
OR
    title LIKE '%test%'
OR
    text LIKE '%test%'
OR
    author LIKE '%test%'
```

The (known) results are composed of records that match the first condition, others that match the second and so on..
However - some of them will match more than one condition.

I want to order them by this order - those who match all 4 `where`'s first, those who match three `where`'s will come second and so on...

I know that the mechanism is preventing it because after the first match, the others are not tested.. is there a way to do it anyway?

I use laravel, so if there is a way to achieve it with laravel, it will do as well.

Comment: How about `Order By (Case When name LIKE '%test%' Then 1 Else 0 End) + (Case When title LIKE '%test%' Then 1 Else 0 End) + ... Desc` ?

Comment: @GMB yap. my bad, wrote 'laravel' without noticing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use something like this:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM articles
WHERE name LIKE '%test%'
   OR title LIKE '%test%'
   OR text LIKE '%test%'
   OR author LIKE '%test%'
ORDER BY 
    (case when name LIKE '%test%'then 1 else 0 end) + 
    (case when title LIKE '%test%' then 1 else 0 end) +
    (case when text LIKE '%test%' then 1 else 0 end) +
    (case when author LIKE '%test%' then 1 else 0 end) desc
```

For different DBMSs you could simplify this a bit. [IF](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_mysql_if.asp) in MySQL, as an example.

Answer (score 1):

Another implementation using subquery

```sql
SELECT
    (t.nameMatched + t.titleMatched + t.textMatched + t.authorMatched) as matchCount,
    name,
    title,
    text,
    author
FROM (
    SELECT 
        name,
        title,
        text,
        author,
        IF (name LIKE '%quant%', 1, 0) as nameMatched,
        IF (title LIKE '%quant%', 1, 0) as titleMatched,
        IF (text LIKE '%quant%', 1, 0) as textMatched,
        IF (author LIKE '%quant%', 1, 0) as authorMatched
    FROM articles
    WHERE
        name LIKE '%quant%' OR
        title LIKE '%quant%' OR
        text LIKE '%quant%' OR
        author LIKE '%quant%'
) t
ORDER BY matchCount DESC
;
```

also if you want to get rid of specifying your like query twice

```sql
SELECT
    (t.nameMatched + t.titleMatched + t.textMatched + t.authorMatched) as matchCount,
    t.nameMatched,
    t.titleMatched,
    t.textMatched,
    t.authorMatched,
    name,
    title,
    text,
    author
FROM (
    SELECT 
        name,
        title,
        text,
        author,
        IF (name LIKE '%quant%', 1, 0) as nameMatched,
        IF (title LIKE '%quant%', 1, 0) as titleMatched,
        IF (text LIKE '%quant%', 1, 0) as textMatched,
        IF (author LIKE '%quant%', 1, 0) as authorMatched
    FROM articles
) t
WHERE
 nameMatched = 1 OR
 titleMatched = 1 OR
 textMatched = 1 OR
 authorMatched = 1
ORDER BY matchCount DESC
;
```